# extracting metadata from jpeg2000 images in python

Tags: python, xml, jpeg2000

I'd like to update the metadata in a series of jpeg2000 images.  And I'd like to do it using python.  I've looked at glymur and have been able to extract the xml etree:

```
import glymur
from lxml import etree

jp2 = glymur.Jp2k(file)
metaroot = jp2.box[3].xml  # 4th element in box contains the metadata I want
fitshdr = metaroot[0]  # the metadata originated as a fits header
```

Then I can get tags and tag values:

```
for kw in fitshdr:
    tag = kw.tag
    val = fitshdr.findtext(tag)
    # do something with tags and values
```

My question is: Is there an easier way?  This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: It was pointed out to me that the sunpy package has nice facilities for this -- see sunpy.io.jp2.get_header or just read in the file via sunpy.io.jp2.read(filepath), which returns a list of (data,header) tuples.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan mentioned, you can use [sunpy](https://sunpy.org/) module, which is popular among solar physicists and astronomers:

```
from sunpy.io import jp2
path_to_jp2 = 'example.jp2'
header = jp2.read(path_to_jp2)  # type:<class 'list'>
```

This function is documented under [sunpy.io](http://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/code_ref/io.html). You can also take a look at its [source code](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/_modules/sunpy/io/jp2.html?highlight=hdpair).